# Programmatically get all tables of a database owned by a user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created the following query:

```
    select 
    is_tables.table_name 
from information_schema.tables is_tables 
join pg_tables 
    on is_tables.table_name=pg_tables.tablename 
where 
    is_tables.table_catalog='<mydatabase>' 
    and is_tables.table_schema<>'information_schema' 
    and is_tables.table_schema<>'pg_catalog' 
    and pg_tables.tableowner='<myuser>';
```

I assume there is no database vendor independent way of querying this. Is this the easiest/shortest SQL query to achieve what I want in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. Object owners don't seem to appear in the information_schema views, although I might have overlooked it.

```
select is_tables.table_schema,
       is_tables.table_name 
from information_schema.tables is_tables 
inner join pg_tables 
        on is_tables.table_name = pg_tables.tablename 
       and is_tables.table_schema = pg_tables.schemaname
where is_tables.table_catalog = '<mydatabase>' 
  and is_tables.table_schema <> 'information_schema' 
  and is_tables.table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' 
  and pg_tables.tableowner = '<myuser>';
```

You need to join on both the table name and the schema name. Table names are unique within a schema; they're not unique within a database.